# English Translation of Milhamoth Hashem by Yiḥyeh Qafiḥ

Tags: product-recommendation, mysticism-kabbalah, zohar

Milhamoth Hashem is Yiḥyeh Qafiḥ's controversial work, presenting his group's philosophy and questioning the authenticity of the Zohar and it's attribution to the sage R' Shimon bar Yohai.

Is there an English translation of it, or an overview?

Comment: Hi Ya'akov, welcome to Mi Yodeya. Great to have you learning with us. Sefaria offers a digital version of this work. Several sentences are translated into English, however, not all of them. See: https://www.sefaria.org/The_Wars_of_God?tab=contents

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there an English translation of it, **or an overview**?

To my knowledge R. Yihyeh Qafih's [ספר מלחמות השם](http://www.yahadut.org.il/ZOHAR/MILHAMOT-HASHEM.PDF) has not been translated to English in its entirety. However the work [Tohar Hayihud](http://www.mesora.org/ToharHayihud.pdf) translates large chunks of it over the span of 30+ pages (from around pp.19-54).